# Is there a bound for the genus of the generalized petersen graphs?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I've looked online and could only find a bound for specific [generalized petersen graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Petersen_graph). Does any bound (lower or upper) depending on $n$ and $k$, where $n$ is the order of a cycle and $k$ is the "jump" in the inner cycle, exist? For example, the Petersen graph is denoted $GP(5,2)$ ($GP$ stands for generalized petersen). Sources to find the information would be appreciated!